# how can I get a country name without using GEOIP functions on Godaddy's web host?

Tags: php, geolocation

I want to get the country name of people who gets in my site, unfortunately I am using a godaddy's hosting account and I cannot use the $_server['geoip_country_name'], but I could install

```
Net_Geo (1.0.5)
Net_GeoIP (1.0.0)
Services_GeoNames (1.0.0)
```

These are pearl modules and services_geonames should help me to get the names, checking the docs I found this:

Looking up the country name

```
<?php
require_once "Net/GeoIP.php";

$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance("/path/to/geoipdb.dat");

try {
    echo $geoip->lookupCountryName($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
?>
```

But I dont really know how to include the .dat library using this hosting, any idea how to use this service? or use another one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upload the .dat file to one of your folders and include it...

Download @ http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/#Downloads

ie; upload to abc/

```
<?php
require_once "Net/GeoIP.php";

$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance("abc/geoipdb.dat");

try {
echo $geoip->lookupCountryName($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
?>
```

Also you can get https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php for use with the maxmind DB